# How to split multi-layered TIFF images with C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, tiff

I am working on a project in which input files are multi-page AND multi-layered TIF files.

I am able to easily write some C# (.NET Core 3.1) code to split the pages. However, the most important part of the job is to split all the different layers (some people call it stacks). I am unable to come up with a solution for this.

I have tried LibTiff.Net, no success. I have tried reading the tif file as a byte array and try to mine the data out of it, no success either.

I cannot find anything in other questions that can get me any closer to an answer.

I do have another file that gives me the offset and length of each image that should be extracted from the tif.

Comment: Have you tried [TiffLibrary](https://github.com/yigolden/TiffLibrary)? It supports both stripped TIFF and tiled TIFF.

Comment: @MichaelChen I have, but still no success with it. It seems to get me really close to what I need, but still stuck in getting all images from each directory.

Comment: Can you share a sample Tiff?